# No GoRouter found in context in widget tests

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-go-router

I'm trying to mock go_router in my widget tests but keep getting this error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
No GoRouter found in context
'package:go_router/src/router.dart':
Failed assertion: line 300 pos 12: 'inherited != null'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      GoRouter.of (package:go_router/src/router.dart:300:12)
#3      GoRouterHelper.pushNamed (package:go_router/src/misc/extensions.dart:50:16)
#4      _ProfileEditWidgetState._getSubmitButton.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:app/widgets/profile/profile_edit_widget.dart:236:33)
```

I'm using go_router 6.0.0

Here's what I have in my test:

```dart
final router = MockGoRouter();
when(router.pushNamed(any)).thenReturn(null);

await tester.pumpWidget(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<ProfileBloc>(create: (context) => profileBloc),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          locale: const Locale("en"),
          home: InheritedGoRouter(
            goRouter: router,
            child: ProfileEditWidget(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

await tester.pump();
await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('btnSubmit')));
await tester.pump();
```

In my profile edit widget in the submit button on pressed this is what I have:

```dart
context.pushNamed(
    VERIFY_PHONE,
     queryParams: {
         'updatedPhone': phone
      },
)
```

There also seems to be no documentation on go to handle testing with go router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the `MaterialApp` to `MaterialApp.router`

And use `GoRouter()` instead of `MockGoRouter()`

```
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

// GoRouter configuration
final _router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => HomeScreen(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have GoRouter set up like how you have mentioned. But the issue occurs in the widget_test.dart file. I still get **No GoRouter found in context**